# Observable as promise nested in promise

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, rxjs

I'm in a scenario where I have a `promise` inside a `promise`. However when calling `.then` on the containing `promise` I'm getting the result of my inner promise. Which is great, but I don't understand why it works. Why can I do this:

```
    this.dataService.init().then(d => console.log(d));
```

instead of this:

```
    this.dataService.init().then(p => p.then(d => console.log(d));
```

**dataservice**

```
  init(){
    return this.geo.init().then( p => this.get(p.lat, p.lon));
  }

  get(lat, lon){
    let uri = `${this.baseuri}lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${this.appid}`
   //this returns a promise
    return this.http.get(uri).toPromise()
      .then(d => d.json() || {}); 
  }
```

**geolocation service**

```
  init(){
    return new Promise( this.getGeolocation );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you return a promise from inside a `.then()` handler, the outer promise and the inner promise become chained together.  The outer promise will then get its value from the inner promise and the outer promise will not call it's `.then()` handlers until the inner promise is resolved.

This is a very powerful and intentional feature of promises.  It allows you to very easily sequence async operations and know what the eventual and final result is.

A promise never resolves with a value that is another promise. When it detects that you returned a promise from a `.then()` handler, it just chains to that promise and uses that new promise's value as the eventual value for the parent promise.

In fact, you can't even purposely make a promise be the resolved value from within a `.then()` handler.  In rare cases where you want a resolved value to be a promise, you have to wrap it in an object (to hide it) and resolve with the non-promise object as the resolved value.

So, in this line:

```
return this.geo.init().then( p => this.get(p.lat, p.lon));
```

Here's the sequence of operations:

1. Call `this.geo.init()`.  That returns a promise, we will call `p1`.
2. Call `.then()` on that promise and pass it a callback.  This registers the `.then()` callback handler to be called later with the previous promise resolves.  It also returns a new promise which is what is returned from your function.  We will call this promise `p2`.  This is one of the keys that allows this to work.
3. Now `p1` resolves eventually.  This calls the `.then()` handler callback registered on it.  This calls `this.get(...)` which returns another promise `p3` which is returned from inside this `.then()` handler as the return value.
4. The promise infrastructure sees that you returned a promise from the `.then()` handler so it links `p2` to `p3` and `p2` does not get resolved until `p3` does and when `p3` does finally get resolved, `p2` uses its resolved value.   The key that makes this work is that `p1` is long since resolved, but `p1.then()` returned a new promise `p2` which is what your top level function returned.  And `p2` gets chained to `p3` so `p2` does not resolve until `p2` does and `p2` gets its resolved value from `p3`.

FYI, you can chain to any arbitrary depth.

Answer (score 1):

The `dataService.init` function returns a promise. When you invoke a function that returns a promise, the parameter that is passed to `.then()` is what you get AFTER the promise has resolved. A promise cannot resolve and return ANOTHER promise to its `.then` callback. It must wait until the inner promise resolves first.

`this.dataService.init().then(d => console.log(d));`

When your callback receives `d`, both promises have already resolved, and `d` is a value, NOT a promise. Therefore it doesn't make sense to call `.then()` on it again.

Essentially, **you can nest functions that return promises as much as you like**. When you call the outermost function, it will wait until all the promises have resolved before returning the final value.

For instance:

```
const getXhrResult = () => axios.get('/some-url') // returns a promise

const func1 = () => getXhrResult().then((res) => {
  console.log('Got the result')
  return result * 2 // also returns a promise
}

const func2 = () => func1().then(console.log)

func2() // logs the result * 2.
```